# Hide validation after return view using mvc5 razor validaiton

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I have two buttons

1) Submit
2) Save and Edit

if user will use **Submit** button all page validation should fire and after he will submit record

if user will use  **Save and Edit** then this button not require any validation will not fire. after clicking save and edit button controller will return on same page no need to show validation after return but its showing validations.

I use **ModelState.Clear();** working fine but dropdown is loosing value after Save and Edit case.

```
  switch (command)
            {
                case "Submit":


                ViewBag.StageInnovation = new SelectList(db.StageofInnovations.OrderBy(k => k.StageName), "StageId", "StageName");

                return View(Application);

                case "Save and Edit":

                ViewBag.StageInnovation = new SelectList(db.StageofInnovations.OrderBy(k => k.StageName), "StageId", "StageName");
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View(Application);
            }
```

Below are html buttons.

```
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="command" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save and Edit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" name="command" />
```

Comment: could you share the code you use to fill the dropdown on view and controller. on common scenario the dropdown value will not loosing value if you send the submitted value back to the view.

Comment: Just redirect back to the GET method